# What action is Yashiro supposed to take?

Tags: erased

In episode 3, Satoru tells his teacher to "hurry up" and do something about Hinazuki at the end of their conversation, and also states in the narration that he's "positive Yashiro is waiting until spring vacation before taking action."

I'm slightly confused. Yashiro earlier says that "the Child Consultation Center visited their house three times." I thus assumed that

- The Child Consultation Center is already worried or suspicious (if they visited Hinazuki's home at all). Yashiro probably informed them about the abuse at Hinazuki's home. (Even if Yashiro didn't, they are already aware of the case.)
- The Child Consultation Center would be the party responsible for any further follow-up or protective measures, not Yashiro.

Am I wrong about this? If I am *not* wrong, what is it that Yashiro must hurry up and do? (Does he simply need to speed up things, given that the Child Consultation Center is "so incompetent"?)

Comment: I think one point you didn't get is that Child Consultation Center visited the house 3 times but every time Hunazuki and her mother were not home. The fact that they came back may not be because they are worried, but because they didn't have anyone to see the previous times

Comment: @Ikaros: true, but I assumed that visiting at all in the first place would indicate a need to check things out.

Comment: I think that they are curious and want to clear things out, but they are not concerned enough to come back every week/month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Satoru simply wanted him to do something, anything, to make sure Kaya would stay safe. He suggested calling the police and getting the counselors to check in again. Satoru wanted the teacher to speed up the process because he was planning to wait until the next school break (Spring, if I remember correctly.)